# How do I go about creating a gem with routes which will be used within a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rubygems, external, rails-engines

Project specs:

- I need to create a gem which has **some routes**.
- The gem will be used by a **Rails** app.
- The Rails app needs to be able to use the routes within the gem.

I read that "Rails Engines" could be a good candidate for this. 
What do you guys think?

The **main thing I am unsure about** is how to go about creating a gem that **contains routes** and will be used by a rails application.

Answer (score 2):

I use Rails Engines all the time. A few things to keep in mind that you will want to most likely keep the engine isolated with a namespace and start creating the engine as a mountable engine.

You have to determine why you want to extract business logic or other functionality out of the main application and into a gem/engine.

I will usually move stuff to create new stuff in an engine if one of the following conditions are met:

- I want to reuse the code in other applications and the parameters
  will be very similar
- The logic of this code is very invasive (meaning that there is a whole lot to this module with either several controllers, models or views).

An example that I can give where I have extracted code and/or created an engine is a real time chat program that I made for an intranet. The number of views and models for this engine ran about 30-40 each. I didn't want to pollute the main application with this ancillary feature but at the same time wanted it to appear that you never left the main application. An engine was great for this. I used the existing user authentication and authorization model to handle the users and their levels of access to the real time chat.

This may help you link between the engine and your main application's models. What I typically do is try to keep my main application as clean as possible and put any associations that are specific to my engine within the engine. There are only a few instances where I found that you have to keep some logic of the engine within the main application (Mailer Previews).

Within my engine, I'll include a file that has something similar below.

```
module MyEngine
  module UserModel
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      has_many :notes, class_name: 'MyEngine::Note'

      def can_post?
        ...
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Within the User Model of the main application, I'll include this as a resource.

```
include MyEngine::UserModel
```

From here, I can within any part of my application access the notes with `current_user.notes` or similar. The methods are also available like `@user.can_post?`.

Comment: thanks for this. I intend to make this gem open source and really, its going to be rather simple. Just a few routes, a single controller and some some helper methods (no views). Would you say a rails engine is my best choice still? What other approaches could I take? The main thing that complicates this for me right now is the fact that I **need routes** in my gem.

Comment: What is the purpose of the engine?

Comment: The purpose of it is to interact with an API. Specifically, an oAuth 1.0 API which requires a callback URL - hence, the necessary routes.

Comment: You wouldn't really need an engine for something like this. Commonly this is done as a gem. In the Readme, specify what the developer would need to add in the routes or create a rake task where it adds it in.

Comment: as of now it will only have two routes but potentially it may expend into closer to ~10 routes. I would like to keep it abstracted out from my main rails.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go with a Rails Engine approach. It was **very simple**.
Rails provide a generator for engines which is very easy to use.

More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)
This guide is very well written.